# Give the results of the following Boolean operations

Tags: boolean

Assuming that A = True, B = False and C = True.
Give the results of the following Boolean operations

AB + BC’ (A + B’C) + B

(b) ABC’ + (B + AC’)B + A’

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

in boolean multiply operation is AND (&&) operation
and plus + operation is OR(||) operation
and '  operator measn NOT(!)

so,

> AB + BC’ (A + B’C) + B

can be written as

> (A && B) || [(B && (!C)) && (A || ((!B) && C))] || B

```
    PUTTING THE VALUE IN THE ABOVE EQUATION
    
    = (1 && 0) || [(0 && (!0)) && (1 || ((!1) && 1))] || 1
    = 0 || [(0 && 1 )&& (1 || (0 && 1)] ||1
    = 0 || [(0 && 1) && (1 || 0)] ||1
    = 0 || [0 && 1] ||1
    = 0 || 0 || 1
    = 1
```

I KNOW IT IS HARD TO FOLLOW BUT THE ANSWER WILL BE 1

AND FOLLOWING THE SAME LOGIC THE ANSWER TO THE 2ND STATEMENT WILL ALSO BE 1

IF YOU WANT TO UNDERSTAND HOW THIS WORKS PLEASE READ THE [DOCS](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/computer_logical_organization/boolean_algebra.htm)